# Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user rendered or redirected Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt, ruby-on-rails-5, auth0

I am trying to setup a Rails API using auth0 for authentication. I have followed the instructions at [Auth0 rails API quickstart](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/rails).
This is how my User model is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
  has_secure_password
  has_many :developed_apps, class_name: "App", foreign_key: "developer_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :installations, foreign_key: "user_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :non_installations, foreign_key: "user_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :installed_apps, through: :installations, class_name: "App", source: :app#, counter_cache: true
  has_many :non_installed_apps, through: :non_installations, class_name: "App", source: :app#, counter_cache: true
  validates :auth0_id_string, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  def self.from_token_payload payload
    # Returns a valid user, `nil` or raise
    # e.g.
    self.find_or_create_by!(auth0_id_string: payload["sub"])
    #self.first
    #nil
  end
end
```

I have just `id`, `auth0_id_string` and `password_digest` fields in user column of db.
My controllers and routes are namespaced like:
`/controllers/api/v1/apps_controller.rb`

```
module Api
  module V1
    class AppsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_user
      before_action :set_app, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
      before_action :require_developer, only: [:update, :destroy]

      ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 2

      def index
        if params[:page]
          @page_no = params[:page].to_i
        else
          @page_no = 1
        end

        if !@page_no.to_i.between?(1,((App.count.to_f/ITEMS_PER_PAGE).ceil))
          render json: { errors: ["Invalid page number."] }, status: 400 and return
        end

        @apps = App.offset((@page_no - 1) * ITEMS_PER_PAGE).limit(ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
        render json: { :last => (@page_no == (App.count.to_f/ITEMS_PER_PAGE).ceil), :data => @apps }
      end

      def show
        render json: @app
      end

      def create
        @app = App.new(app_params)
        @app.developer = current_user

        if @app.save
          render json: @app
        else
           render json: { errors: ["Invalid attributes."] }, status: 400
        end
      end

      def update
        if @app.update(app_params)
          render json: @app
        else
          render json: { errors: ["Invalid attributes."] }, status: 400
        end
      end

      def destroy
        if @app.destroy
          render json: { errors: ["Deletion successful."] }, status: 200
        else
          render json: { errors: ["Deletion failed."] }, status: 500
        end
      end

      private

      def set_app
        @app = App.find(params[:id])
      end

      def require_developer
        if current_user != @app.developer
          render json: { errors: ["Authorized users only."] }, status: :unauthorized
        end
      end

      def app_params
        params.require(:app).permit(:name, :description, :blob_location)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

`routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :apps
    end
  end
end
```

I have added `bcrypt` to Gemfile for `has_secure_password`.
`application_controller.rb` as knock gem readme says its required:

`/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include Knock::Authenticable
end
```

I am including `Authorization` in header as `Bearer <jwt_token>`, the token I have verified is correct from jwt.io and other sites.
HTTP snippet from Postman:

```
GET /api/v1/apps HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InNpZC5zd2FwbmlsZGV2ZXNoQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjp0cnVlLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NpZGV2ZXNoLmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJhdXRoMHw1ODkxNDMxZDg1OGQwNDY5YjgwOGFmZmEiLCJhdWQiOiJ1NFhpZUxoRzBJMUZ5YmxGNFFaSWZVN2JkdDhkcm5CZSIsImV4cCI6MTQ4NTk1MjA0NCwiaWF0IjoxNDg1OTE2MDQ0fQ.rRExJkabeB_xrdHpsUIELA9jUSJZq4mxlkDMt6T-OgA
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 4dc93848-3f9d-6366-3a01-c4f6a86a7640
```

Here is my Gemfile for version info:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'knock', '~> 2.0'
gem "paranoia", "~> 2.2"
# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
# gem 'rack-cors'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Everytime I am sending a request all I am getting is the response mentioned in title.
Although I noticed that if I remove Authorization from header, I am getting this in log:

```
Started GET "/api/v1/apps" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-01 15:27:38 +0530
Processing by Api::V1::AppsController#index as JSON
  User Load (77.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."auth0_id_string" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."auth0_id_string" IS NULL AND "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 299ms (ActiveRecord: 80.8ms)
```

Why is this not working with this configuration ? Am I missing something ?
I noticed similar issue in auth0 forums but that was regarding some old issue in ruby-jwt gem which for my current version of `jwt` gem should have been resolved, yet I also tries that solution with no difference in result. [Link](https://auth0.com/forum/t/angularjs-rails-authenticate-401-unauthorized-in-1ms/2244/3).

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `Authorization` header, the `authenticate_user` method will fail, as it can not authenticate the user, this is expected behaviour and what you should expect to see in your log.

What URL are you hitting to receive the response in the title?

Comment: Looking at the source of knock gem, behavior when no Authorization is in header makes sense...I just can't get it to work when there is correct header in request...http://localhost:300/api/v1/apps @Michael

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured this out...
First,
the secret key I got from auth0 was not base64 encoded, so the commented out line in the generated initializer of knock (`/config/initializers/knock.rb`) for auth0, which decoded the secret key as base64 ended up giving wrong key,
Now I am using this:

```
config.token_secret_signature_key = -> { Rails.application.secrets.auth0_client_secret }
```

Second,
I was only able to figure this out by overriding `define_current_entity_getter` method in my `application_controller.rb` and removing the `rescue`. This agressive rescue causes it to fail silently and needs to be fixed.